# Does FileDescriptor.sync() work for all file data or just file data originating within the callers JVM

Tags: java, caching, synchronization, flush, file-descriptor

Will this ensure that all data is synced on the local machine or just data originating within the currently operation JVM?

```
FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(filename)
s.getFD().sync()

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(null);
fis.getFD().sync();
```

Context: we have many programs (other software) that write to a file that we share. We all lock it when we use it, and unlock it after, ... but we are finding that the OS is not fully synced to the file store (network drive) even though everyone is done with their files.

Even after a lock is acquired, it seems that the OS is not fsycn'ed with the the file and that some of the last data has not been written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does FileDescriptor.sync() work for all file data

No.

> or just file data originating within the callers JVM

It works on the *current file descriptor* only, which is necessarily within the caller's JVM, along with the data he is writing.